# Spring Controller not called

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

The following controller is not called. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

```
package com.mnox.corporate.controllers;

@Controller
public class OnLoadAddDriverController extends ADriverModel implements IController {

    public static final String allDomainOrGroupParentDetails = "allDomainOrGroupParentDetails";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/onLoadAddDriverView")
    public ModelAndView onLoadAddDriver(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        try {
            return new OnLoadAddDriverDataLoader().getModelData(getModelViewName(), httpServletRequest);
        } catch (InvalidObjectStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null ;
        }

    }

class OnLoadAddDriverDataLoader extends ADataLoader {
```

The abstract base class

```
@Controller
public abstract class ADriverModel extends AErrorFactory implements IView {
```

My `catalina.out` shows the following

> INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/onLoadAddDriverView],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.mnox.corporate.controllers.OnLoadAddDriverController.onLoadAddDriver(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Shows that the controller was loaded. But then I link into this jsp.

My side menu has this code

```
<li id="onLoadAddDriverView"><a
href="javaScript:goBack('<c:url value="onLoadAddDriverView"/>')"><i
class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Add</a></li>
```

What happens is that my login page loads instead of `onLoadAddDriverView.jsp`.

**EDIT**

My authentication filter was messed up. I debugged thru it and realized that this page was not getting its due attention.

Comment: "...my login page loads instead..." suggests that your client needs to have been authenticated (logged in) before it can access your controller.

Comment: Yeah, there was an issue with my AuthenticationFilter defaulting to the login page. Please put up an answer.